# How do I change inline CSS styles using a variable in JSX inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Okay, so I have a map function that is running through an array and creating divs on the DOM for each item ("colorItem") in the array. The array is an array of colors, each item in the array is the hex value of a color (example: `#1a703f`).

I'm trying to change the background of each div item so it matches the item from the array. However because I cant get access the variable inside the map function inside the inline CSS JSX.

```
{this.state.colorsArray.map(colorItem =>

      <div className="m-4">
        <div className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg w-48">
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: {colorItem} }} className="h-32">
          </div>
          <div className="px-6 py-4">
            <p className="text-grey-darker">
              {colorItem}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

`

Comment: Try `style={{ backgroundColor: colorItem }}`

Comment: @ChrisG Wow, I thought for sure I tried that, but it worked - thanks!

Comment: Once you are inside the first/outer set of `{}` braces, you are again in a JavaScript context, where `{...}` means to create an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
{this.state.colorsArray.map(colorItem => {
  let colorstyle = {
     backgroundColor: colorItem
  }
  return (
  <div className="m-4">
    <div className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg w-48">
      <div style={colorstyle} className="h-32">
      </div>
      <div className="px-6 py-4">
        <p className="text-grey-darker">
          {colorItem}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the parameter in the lambda 'backgroundColor', you can use this object short-notation:

```
{this.state.colorsArray.map(backgroundColor =>
  <div className="m-4">
    <div className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg w-48">
      <div style={{ backgroundColor }} className="h-32">
      </div>
      <div className="px-6 py-4">
        <p className="text-grey-darker">
          {backgroundColor}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```